# Number of monotonic set functions from all the subsets of some finite set to 0 or 1

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Let $N=\{1,2,\ldots n\}$ be some finite set.

Let $f:P(N)\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ be a function such that $A\subset B\rightarrow f(A)\leq f(B)$

I'm trying to find an upper bound to the number of such functions.

Furthermore, I'll call $i,j$ symmetric in $f$ if $\forall A\in P(N)$ with $i,j\not\in A$, $f(A\cup\{i\})=f(A\cup\{j\})$. $f$ is symmetric if there is at least one pair that is symmetric in $f$.

Is there a lower bound on the number of symmetric monotonic functions?

Answer (score 1):

Your first question, about the number of monotonic functions $f:P([n])\to\{0,1\}$ where $[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, is a classic known as [Dedekind's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_number).

Your second question is easier. There are $n+2$ symmetric monotonic functions $f:P([n])\to\{0,1\}$, namely, the two constant functions, and for each $k\in[n]$ the function
$$f(X)=\begin{cases}
0\text{ if }|X|\lt k,\\
1\text{ if }|X|\ge k.\\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I actually meant in symmetric that if there exists such a pair, and not if it is true for any such pair. I'll edit the original question. However the name for the problem will greatly help me look further into it.

Answer (score 0):

How tight an upper bound do you want/need?

A simple, but clearly in no way strict, upper bound is $2^{(2^n)}$ - i.e. the total number of functions $\mathcal{P}(N) \rightarrow 2$.

However, this upper bound assumes you can choose the values of a function on each element of $\mathcal{P}(N)$ independently, which is certainly not the case with the given condition.

***For a slightly better bound;***

Consider the chain (under inclusion) $\emptyset, \{1\}, \{1,2\}, ..., N$.

There are $2^{n+1}$ possible restrictions of a function to this chain, but only $n+2$ of them satisfy $A \subseteq B \Rightarrow f(A) \leq f(B)$.

If we were to then choose the values for the rest of $\mathcal{P}(N)$ as if independently, we now have an upper bound of $(n+2)2^{(2^n - n - 1)}$. This is still not tight, since clearly the function on this chain restricts the allowable values on the rest of $\mathcal{P}(N)$.

***For a slightly better bound again;***

Consider once more the chain $\emptyset, \{1\}, \{1,2\}, ..., N$. Call this chain $C$.

If $f : \mathcal{P}(N) \rightarrow 2$ satisfies the given condition;

Suppose no member of $C$ has image $1$. Then in particular $N \mapsto 0$, and hence all subsets of $N$ map to $0$, i.e. $f \equiv 0$.

Suppose every member of $C$ has image $1$. Then in particular $\emptyset \mapsto 1$, and hence all supersets of $\emptyset$ map to $1$, i.e. $f \equiv 1$.

Suppose the least member of $C$ that has image $1$ has size $k$, $0 < k < n$. Then this set has $\sum_{i\geq k} {n - k \choose i - k} = 2^{n-k}$ supersets (including itself) which must map to 1, and it's predecessor in $C$ has $2^{k-1}$ subsets (including itself) which must map to 0.
$k$ therefore determines the value of $f$ on $2^{n-k} + 2^{k-1}$ elements of $\mathcal{P}(N)$.

If we allowed the values of the rest of $\mathcal{P}(N)$ to be chosen independently of each other, this would give $2^{2^n - 2^{n-k} - 2^{k-1}}$ functions for a given k.

Summing over possible $k$, we get an upper bound of $2 + \sum_{1 \leq k < n} 2^{2^n - 2^{n-k} - 2^{k-1}}$

(This might simplify, but I haven't looked to closely at the algebra to do so)

Looking in similar ways will give more refinements to the bound at the cost of more complicated reasoning - go as far as you need to go for whatever you want this for, I guess, up to the point of working out exactly how many such functions there are.